# Dynamic filters operation for supabase api

Tags: typescript, supabase, supabase-database

How to define type of filterOperation in this case?

`let response = supabase.from('accounts').select(*)`

Use:

`response = response[filterOperation](field, value)`

Instead of:

`response = response.eq(field, value)`

I tried several ways but still got the error: can't be used to index type 'PostgrestFilterBuilder<any, any, any[], unknown>'

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before by using the [match filter](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/match).

```
const query = supabase.from('users').select('*').match(query ?? {});
```

The query variable should look like so... `{ name: 'John', age: 27 }`

OR leave it null to get all results.

**EDIT 2023.10.12:**

Something like this should work:

```
const query = supabase.from('users').select('*');

filters.forEach(filter  => {
    switch (filter.operator) {
        case 'eq':
            query = query.eq(filter.field, filter.value)
            break;
        case 'neq':
            query = query.neq(filter.field, filter.value)
            break;
        case 'like':
            query = query.like(filter.field, filter.value)
            break;
        ...
    }
});

const {data, error} = await query();
```

The filters object would look something like this:

```
[{
    operator: 'qe',
    field: 'name',
    value: 'john'
}, 
...]
```

*I've done something similar to this to dynamically add an `or` condition and it worked.*

Comment: Actually, match is only for the `eq` operator. Here I want dynamic type of filed because there are some other operators (gt, gte, lt, lte,..). Fixed it by declaring its type like this: `type FilterOperator = 'eq'| 'neq'| 'gt'| 'gte'| 'lt'| 'lte'| 'like'| 'ilike';`

Comment: Gotcha I've edited my post with an example of something that should work.